# Stored Procedure Duplicating Results

Tags: sql, caching, stored-procedures, duplicates

I am calling a stored procedure twice and it is giving me odd results. 
The stored procedure's goal is to create an exam with data loaded into it. It has char(1) parameter that passes in 'A' or 'B' So when I call the stored procedure it will look like:

```
Execute Create_Test 'A'
Execute Create_Test 'B'
```

It works fine, it creates two tests. The char(1) tells it what questions to pull from the database those marked as 'A' or 'B' which also works. If these two stored procedures are called sequentially however, it causes some issues. The first stored procedure will run twice for some reason, but only part of it will.

Here is what is in the stored procedure:

```
-- Code that creates @intTestID is up here and does things    

--Add Question Records
Insert Into Question (Test_ID, Question_Text, Question_Type_ID, Question_Stem_ID)
Select @intTestID as Test_ID, Question as Question_Text, Question_Type_ID, Question_Stem_ID
From Question_Stem
Where TestCreationProcessID = @pintTestCreationProcessID and Test_Form = @pstrForm --(or 'B' if passed)

--Add Answer Records
Insert Into Answer (Question_ID, Answer_Text, isCorrect, Question_Stem_Answer_ID)
Select Question_ID, Answer as Answer_Text, isCorrect, QSA.Question_Stem_Answer_ID
From Question_Stem_Answer QSA
    Inner Join Question Q On Q.Question_Stem_ID = QSA.Question_Stem_ID
    Inner Join Test T On Q.Test_ID = T.Test_ID and T.isActive=1
Where T.TestCreationProcessID = @pintTestCreationProcessID
```

This results in two tests being created but test 'A' will have all of its answers duplicated. So instead of 4 answers, it has 8 answers. The other 4 always being the same as the first 4. The questions themselves do not end up duplicating which is completely bizarre.

If I were to select "Create_Test 'A'" then run it, then select "Create_Test 'B'" then run it, it does not duplicate the answers in either form. Only if I highlight both of them and run it do they duplicate the answers.

Some more information:
This is creating 'A's answers twice. The first time all of 'A's answers are created sequentially. So ID 1-100 will be unique answers belonging to 'A'. When 'B' Runs it creates all of 'A's answers again and 'B's answers at the same time resulting in Answer_IDs 101-300 being a mix between 'A' and 'B' answers.

What it should do, is 1-100 will belong to 'A' and 101-200 will belong to 'B'

I think it may be the result of some caching, but if that is so, then why wouldn't the questions also display twice? It is also only whatever Stored Procedure is called first that gets duplicated. Independently they run fine, together (which is highly preferable) they duplicate.

I tried creating two stored procedures, Create_Test_A and Create_Test_B and running those back to back. Same duplication occurs. I have tried putting a sleep in between these, to no avail. I honestly don't want a work around (though I may have to do that) I'd prefer a solution. It is to me, a quite fascinating occurrence. I spoke to some other developers who had also never seen this before.

Sorry if this is really confusing, I gave my best shot at explaining what is going on. If you need any more info I'll supply it if I can.

Comment: I think there is an issue with your insert statement for the Answer table.  Since it joins on Question, what is keeping inserts from happening for existing Questions and Tests?  Is it supposed to be bound by the isActive flag that might remain true for multiple tests running back to back?  I think you should bound that insert by some sort of ID.

Comment: Fixed, I tried to remove information that wasn't entirely necessary.

Comment: One thing that I would try when debugging these issues is to update the stored procedures to run the same exact select statement on it's own before doing running it to insert into tables.  This will allow you to run those back-to-back statements in Management Studio and see the result sets.  This will hopefully lead to to the exact statement that is causing problems so you can focus your efforts.